# How to merge two javascript arrays based on property values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge

I have two arrays

```
array1 = [{"id":1,"name":"Michale Sharma","gender":"Male","age":25,"salary":10000},{"id":2,"name":"Sunil Das","gender":"Male","age":24,"salary":5000},{"id":3,"name":"Robin Pandey","gender":"Male","age":35,"salary":45000},{"id":4,"name":"Mona Singh","gender":"Female","age":27,"salary":12000}] 

array2 = [{"Deptid":1,"Deptname":"IT"},{"Deptid":12,"Deptname":"HR"},{"Deptid":3,"Deptname":"HW"}]
```

**Output:**

```
{ "0": { "id": 1, "name": "Michale Sharma", "gender": "Male", "age": 25, "salary": 10000, "Deptid": 1, "Deptname": "IT" }, "1": { "id": 2, "name": "Sunil Das", "gender": "Male", "age": 24, "salary": 5000}, "2": { "id": 3, "name": "Robin Pandey", "gender": "Male", "age": 35, "salary": 45000, "Deptid": 3, "Deptname": "HW" }, "3": { "id": 4, "name": "Mona Singh", "gender": "Female", "age": 27, "salary": 12000 }, "4" :{ "Deptid": 12, "Deptname": "HR" } }
```

[image: Image of requested output in table form]

I want to merge them based on the property values e.g **id of array1** and **Deptid of array2**

Which means if id value = 1 and Deptid value = 1, then merge the records, if not then keep the values from one array and the other will be null. In another words, *kind of the functionality of FULL OUTER JOIN*. Because the array data cannot be a sequential one and may not be of the same length.

I have tried with **Jquery.extend**  as under

```
$.extend(true, array1,array2)
```

It does not accept any property but merges the arrays.

I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529329/how-to-merge-2-arrays-based-on-properties-not-index) but it does not help.

Comment: There's no way for any generic method to know that the id property of one array's objects is to be matched to the Deptid property on the other array's objects. You'll need to write some code to loop through each.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to have a custom logic. Here is sample using lodash library:

```
var array1 = [{"id":1,"name":"Michale Sharma","gender":"Male","age":25,"salary":10000},{"id":2,"name":"Sunil Das","gender":"Male","age":24,"salary":5000},{"id":3,"name":"Robin Pandey","gender":"Male","age":35,"salary":45000},{"id":4,"name":"Mona Singh","gender":"Female","age":27,"salary":12000}] 
var array2 = [{"Deptid":1,"Deptname":"IT"},{"Deptid":12,"Deptname":"HR"},{"Deptid":3,"Deptname":"HW"}] 

var defaults = {
    Deptid: null,
    DeptName: null
};

_.each(array1, function (obj) {
    var dept = _.find(array2, { Deptid: obj.id });
    _.defaults(obj, dept, defaults);
});
```

Comment: This isn't going to get you the row with just the HR department

Comment: That's right, need one more loop, but same concept applies.

Answer (score 0):

Using LoDash, roughly something like this:

```
_.reduce(array1, function(res, item1) {
  var found = _.find(array2, function(item2) {
    return item1.id === item2.Deptid;
  });
  if (found) res.push(_.merge({}, item1, found));
  return res;
}, []);
```

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot about merging empty props.

It would be something like this (unoptimized):

```
function join(array1, array2) {
  var keys = _.keys(array2[0]);
  var vals = _.map(keys, function() { return '' });

  return _.map(array1, function(item1) {
    var found = _.find(array2, function(item2) {
      return item1.id === item2.Deptid;
    });

    if (found)
      return _.merge({}, item1, found);

    return _.merge({}, item1, _.zipObject(keys, vals));
  }, []);  
}
```